# Rectangle inside an ellipse that is inside a rectangle

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, area

Suppose there is a rectangle $ABCD$ with $A=(-2,1), B=(-2,-1), C=(2,-1), D=(2,1).$ Then we have an ellipse $\frac{x^2}{4} + y^2=1$ that is tangent to the rectangle. Then we build the rectangle $EFGH$ which has the corners as the intersection of the ellipse and the diagonals of $ABCD$ as can be seen in [image: the image].

The question is that how do we prove $\textbf{analytically}$ that $\frac{A(ABCD)}{A(EFGH)}=2$ for any ellipse?

I already know that it is really easy and cool to prove it by using the homeomorphism of the ellipse and the circle by deforming the question into the easier form.

Comment: Find the coordinates of $F$ and $H$ by solving the system $\frac{x^2}{4} + y^2 = 1$, $y = \frac{x}{2}$. Same for $E$ and $G$. You can now compute the area of $EFGH$ without efforts.

Comment: Clever! How can we prove that for all rectangles and ellipses?

Comment: You can always choose a change of basis to get back to this case. This is equivalent to your original proof with the affine transformation into a square. Or, you can still solve the equations for $E$, $F$, $G$ and $H$, but in some cases it might be harder to find the ratio of $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the analytical proof you are looking for?

[image: TwoRectanglesOneEllipse]

Comment: It is exactly the proof/solution that I wanted. Thanks!